# Rendering server control in a callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I have a bunch of different panels that are custom server controls, which inherits  CompositeControl. The panels are rendered by using the CreateChildControls(). I have a page where I am displaying them based off of a users selection from a comboBox. When you change the selection it does a callback for a callback panel (DevExpress control), which is like an update panel. Based on the selection it adds the panel to the callback panel. But it seems that if you do this from a callback the server controls life cycle doesn't get started, so it never calls CreateChildControls() or OnPreRender(). Any ideas on how to make this work? EnsureChildControls() doesn't seem to helping.

Here is some example code of one of the panels

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        String strParentID = this.ClientInstanceName.Length > 0 ? this.ClientInstanceName : this.ClientID;
        String strID = "";//Used as ID and ClientInstanceName.
        String strKey = "";//Used in the ID and as the ControlInfo key.

        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            //*******************************************************************

            ASPxLabel lblUnit = new ASPxLabel();
            lblUnit.Text = "Select Unit(s)";
            callbackEdit.Controls.Add(lblUnit);

            //*******************************************************************

            strKey = "btnUnitSelector";
            strID = strParentID + "_" + strKey;
            btnUnitSelector = new ASPxButton()
            {
                ID = strID,
                ClientInstanceName = strID,
                CssFilePath = this.CssFilePath,
                CssPostfix = this.CssPostfix,
                SpriteCssFilePath = this.SpriteCssFilePath,
            };

            btnUnitSelector.Width = Unit.Pixel(180);
            btnUnitSelector.AutoPostBack = false;

            this.listControlInfo.Add(new ControlInfo(strKey, btnUnitSelector.ClientInstanceName, btnUnitSelector.ClientID));
            callbackEdit.Controls.Add(btnUnitSelector);

            //*******************************************************************

            strKey = "unitPopup";
            strID = strParentID + "_" + strKey;

            unitPopup = new UnitPopup.UnitPopup();
            unitPopup.ID = strID;
            unitPopup.ClientInstanceName = strID;
            unitPopup.btnOk_AutoPostBack = false;
            unitPopup.ShowOnlyUnits = false;
            unitPopup.DataSource = GlobalProperties.Company_UnitsAndAreas;
            unitPopup.DataBind();
            btnUnitSelector.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function (s, e) { " + unitPopup.ClientInstanceName + ".Show(); }";
            unitPopup.ClientSideEvents.MemberSet = "function (s, e) { " + btnUnitSelector.ClientInstanceName + ".SetText(" + unitPopup.ClientInstanceName + ".selectedMemberName); }";

            Controls.Add(unitPopup);
            //*******************************************************************
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        ClientScriptManager cs = this.Page.ClientScript;

        //Register an embedded JavaScript file. The JavaScript file needs to have a build action of "Embedded Resource".
        String resourceName = "QSR_ServerControls.Controls.DashboardControls.SalesChart.SalesChart.js";
        cs.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(SalesChart), resourceName);
    }
```

Here is some sample code of adding a panel

```
    private void PopulatePanel(string panel)
    {
        tblDescCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(GetPanels().Select("[PanelName] = '" + panel + "'")[0]["PanelDescription"].ToString()));
        if (panel == "SalesChart")
            tblTopLeftCell.Controls.Add(new SalesChart.SalesChart());
    }

    void callbackMain_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {
        PopulatePanel(e.Parameter);
    }
```

Comment: Show us some code, how do you create and add your control to the page controls?

Answer (score 0):

During callback requests PreRender and Render methods are not executed (this is the main difference from PostBack request). But CreateChildControls should be executed. Please provide more information or code example.